# Как сравнить array с value - jquery

Tags: jquery, массивы, сравнение

Есть массив 1,3,5 и есть select где каждая опция имеет value='число'.

Нужно сравнить массив с option value='число'

Если в value есть совпадения с числами из массива, то добавить атрибут selected

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var arr = [1,3,5];

    $('.click').click(function() {
      //????????????????
    });
});
```

```css
select{
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
}

.click {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='click'>click</div>

<select multiple>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
    <option value='5'>5</option>
    <option value='6'>6</option>
    <option value='7'>7</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("select").val(arr);
```

*(minimal'naja dlina tela 30 simvolov)*

Comment: Как все просто, до этого варианта я не додумался. Спасибо. https://jsfiddle.net/j7pm1b6y/1/

Comment: @Sincopa На здоровье. Успехов в программировании!